# Ormconfig to DataSource in typeorm 0.3?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have a project with an API using `TypeScript`, `NestJS` and `typeorm`.

I am using `typeorm` version 0.2 but cause of security issues I have to upgrade to version 0.3 and there were a lot of changes. Now I am not sure, if I understand the `DataSource` correctly, which I haven't used before.

Before I used a `ormconfig.ts` file, not a json:

```js
// ormconfig.ts

import "dotenv/config";
import * as path from "path";
import { ConnectionOptions } from "typeorm";

const connectionOptions: ConnectionOptions = {
    type: "postgres",
    host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.TYPEORM_PORT as string),
    username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
    entities: [path.join(__dirname, "**", "*.entity.{ts,js}")],
    cache: true,
    synchronize: false,
    migrationsRun: false,
    migrations: ["build/src/migration/*.js"],
    cli: {
        migrationsDir: "./migration",
    },
};

export = connectionOptions;
```

And use it in `app.module.ts` like this:

```js
// app.module.ts

import connectionOptions = require("./ormconfig");

@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(connectionOptions),
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And if I need a transaction I used Injection:

```js
// my-entity.service.ts

@Injectable()
export class MyEntityService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(MyEntity)
        @InjectConnection() private connection: Connection
    ) {}
}
```

But now `Connection` is depreacted, the `cli` property isn't available for `PostgreSQL`, and you should use `DataSource`.

I am doing this now and using this connection in `app.module.ts` like before:

```js
// ormconfig.ts

import "dotenv/config";
import * as path from "path";
import { PostgresConnectionOptions } from "typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresConnectionOptions";

const connectionOptions: PostgresConnectionOptions = {
    type: "postgres",
    host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.TYPEORM_PORT as string),
    username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
    entities: [path.join(__dirname, "**", "*.entity.{ts,js}")],
    logging: process.env.TYPEORM_LOGGING === "true",
    cache: true,
    // Migrations
    synchronize: false,
    migrationsRun: false,
    migrations: ["build/src/migration/*.js"],
};

export = connectionOptions;
```

I've added a `data-source.ts`:

```js
// data-source.ts

import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import connectionOptions = require("./ormconfig");

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource(connectionOptions);
```

I've changed `Connection` to `DataSource`:

```js
// my-entity.service.ts

@Injectable()
export class MyEntityService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(MyEntity)
        @InjectConnection() private dataSource: DataSource
    ) {}
}
```

And cause of the missing `cli` property in the  `ConnectionOptions`, I am using now the new CLI command with the migrations path and the data source instead of my old ormconfig file:

```bash
typeorm migration:generate ./src/migrations/update-my-entity-table -d ./src/data-source.ts
```

It seems all to work. Is this the right way?
Does the `@InjectConnection()` and changing from `Connection` to `DataSource` do all the job I needed?
Cause I never use the exported `AppDataSource` anywhere.

I am also not using `[import reflect-metadata][1]` anywhere like the `typeorm` documentation says.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest will take the options you've passed and create a DataSource instance, so `@InjectDataSource()` still works just fine.The `AppDataSource` you have should pretty much just be for your `CLI` for ease of use.

Also, `@nestjs/common` imports `reflect-metadata` so you shouldn't have to worry about that either.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I used `@InjectConnection()` cause this also could take `DataSource`. `@InjectDataSource()` is also decalred deprectaed, I think

Comment: `@InjectDataSource()` is a new decorator in the `@nestjs/typeorm` package. It's not going to be deprecated yet